# linux C++ xlib, does the processor go to fast?

Tags: c++, linux, xlib

here something sound like tricky for me, actualy i'm using Xlib to draw some windows. One is for plotting some 2D results in a image, so this one is drawn only when all calculus are done. another one is a simple window wich says, "calculus in process".

- So now before I start the calculus I call "show me the simple window "calculus in process"",
- then I call the function who does the calculs and plots the result,
- then I call "don't show me the simple window "calculus in process"".

but the problem ams, I don't see the "show me the simple window "calculus in process"" during the calculus, I just see it one instant and disappears just when the image of results of calculs is shown. I try to put some `sleep()` but that doesn't solve the problem. What kind of stuff can cause such problem ? I already met such problem during my C++ course, at that time I worked on console, I never found the reason of such problem.

Can somebody give me some explanation and tips to help me to deal with it like a boss ?

here a piece of sh.. of my code :

```
switch(e.type/*xlibevent*/){
      .
      .
      .
      case KeyRelease      :
        switch(keyRelease()){ // keyRelease just recognize wich key was released
            .
            .
            .       // w3w1 = window "calculus in process"
          case 3  : w3w1.switcher(); doCalculus(&w1); w3w1.switcher(); break;
            .
            .
            .
      .
      .
      .
        }
```

I just did a test, I swap `doCalculus(&w1)` with `sleep(3)` same result, I don't see my window "calculus in process"

there is the `switcher()` ***corrected***

```
  void switcher(){
    if(this->visible==0){
      XMapWindow(dpy,this->window); // what I though before : has to map the window 
                                    // what I think now : request to map the window
      XDrawString(dpy, this->window, this->gc, 10, 14, text.c_str(), text.length());
      XFlush(dpy); // dats what missed, not sure that efficient to flush the dpy
                   // but I deal with the part of xlib I know, I will check further
                   // about that
      visible=1;
    }else{
      XUnmapWindow(dpy,this->window);
      XFlush(dpy); //...
      visible=0;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for dealing with it like a boss.

Comment: Are you running the calculations in the same thread as the rest of the GUI handling?  If so, perhaps the calculations are holding off execution of the GUI's event loop, so that the windows don't get updated until after the calculations complete?

Comment: I would like to show you my code, but it's big... I'm running the gui and calculs in same thread, but since it does one thing at a time I don't understand why it doesn't wait to show me the simple window before starting the calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main event loop is probably blocked by your calculation.  Thus nothing can be displayed as long as you are busy computing.  If you return to the X event loop at least once after displaying the temporary window it should appear (though it may not refresh properly because it won't respond to exposure events).  The best solution is to run your calculations in another thread.

Your confusion about "why it doesn't wait to show me the simple window" is based on a misconception about how X clients work.  There is more interaction between the client and the server (even to do simple things) than you might intuitively expect.

Comment: you right about my misconception. I added `XFlush(dpy)` in `switcher()` then everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this isn't an OpenGL question, but [this OpenGL tutorial](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux%3a_GLX_and_Xlib) can shed some light into this issue. Basically, you're not processing the 'windows' messages to allow for the window you've created to show up. Check the `while(1)` loop in the wiki.

You have two choices:

1. Run your calculation in steps. Where each step gets processed by each call within the while loop
2. Run your calculation in a separate thread, query for progress in every frame from within the `while(1)` loop and display it.

Personally, I'd prefer 2.

Comment: my while is similar to the one in the tutorial, excepted I'm using `switch` instead of `if/else` for convenience. I guess you right about using a separate thread. But what I really want to understand, is, if I have only one thread, should it not finished `w3w1.switcher()` before starting `doCalculus(&w1) / sleep(3)` ? for me it looks like the compiler has merged `w3w1.switcher(); doCalculus(&w1); w3w1.switcher(); break;` and decided by itself to not doing the first `w3w1.switcher()` before the `doCalculus(&w1) / sleep(3)` is done.. I want to understand, because if I think wrong it's not good..

Comment: for answer look at my `switcher()` method. Thx for your comment